# PHP-SQL: If-else correctly displays output of code block, but queries within do not execute

Tags: php, if-statement

I have put together php code that adds, deletes and updates records of book stocks in a database. The books are classified according to genre and when I select the genre (eg. horror) from a dropdown, details of all books from that genre will display. *The code works as intended*.

Now I decided to use an if-else (or switch-case) to display records according to genre. And for now using just one genre (classics), to see if it works. The output is fine, but the actual code for deleting, editing and adding isn't running (the code for delete, edit and update works fine when not in the if block). Would really appreciate some advice on why this is so?

Below is the code - the if statement is right there at the start after the dropdown (have improved below code block by putting the code within the if block into a separate file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php // sqltest.php
  require_once 'login_news.php'; 
  include ('css.php');
  $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error); ?>

  <form action="sqltest.php" method="POST" name="theForm" id="theForm">
          <select name="options">
              <option value="classics">Classics</option>
              <option value="horror">Horror</option>
              <option value="recipes">Recipes</option>
              <option value="historic">Historic</option>
              <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
              <option value="educational">Educational</option>
           </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Load page" />
   </form>



<?php      $selection = $_POST['options'];
            if ($selection == "classics"){  
              include ('classics.php');  
            }    
?>


</html>
```

Classics.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>      

<?php    
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbndel']))
  {
    $isbn   = get_post($conn, 'isbndel');
    $query  = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }


  if (isset($_POST['author'])   &&
      isset($_POST['title'])    &&
      isset($_POST['category']) &&
      isset($_POST['year'])     &&
      isset($_POST['isbn']) &&
      isset($_POST['btn'])) 

  {
    $author   = get_post($conn, 'author');
    $title    = get_post($conn, 'title');
    $category = get_post($conn, 'category');
    $year     = get_post($conn, 'year');
    $isbn     = get_post($conn, 'isbn');

            $filetmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
            $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
            $filepath = "images/".$filename;

            move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);            

    $query    = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
      "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn', '$filename', '$filepath', '$filetype')";
    $result   = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }

//var_dump($_FILES['image2']);
if ($_FILES['image2'])
  {
    $ed_author   = get_post($conn, 'ed_author');
    $ed_title    = get_post($conn, 'ed_title');
    $ed_category = get_post($conn, 'ed_category');
    $ed_year     = get_post($conn, 'ed_year');
    $hid_isbn     = get_post($conn, 'hid_isbn');

        if($_FILES['image2']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
                $filetmp = $_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"];
                        $filename = $_FILES["image2"]["name"];
                        $filetype = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
                        $filepath = "images/".$filename;

                        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);        

                $query    = "UPDATE classics SET author='$ed_author', title='$ed_title', type='$ed_category', year='$ed_year', filename='$filename', filepath='$filepath', filetype='$filetype'WHERE isbn='$hid_isbn'";



                $result   = $conn->query($query);

                    if (!$result) echo "EDIT with image failed: $query<br>" .
                      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
                      $result   = $conn->query($query);     

          }
        else{
            $query  = "UPDATE classics SET author='$ed_author', title='$ed_title', type='$ed_category', year='$ed_year' WHERE isbn='$hid_isbn'";

            $result   = $conn->query($query);

            if (!$result) echo "EDIT with image failed: $query<br>" . $conn->error . "<br><br>";

        }

    }     


?>

  <form action="sqltest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><pre>
    Author <input type="text" name="author">
     Title <input type="text" name="title">
  Category <input type="text" name="category">
      Year <input type="text" name="year">
      ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn">
           <input type="file" name="image">
           <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Upload Image & ADD RECORD">




  </pre></form>

<?php
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM classics";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

  $rows = $result->num_rows;


  while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
  {
?>
  <div class="slab">    
  <div class="present">
        <pre>
        Author <?php echo $row[0]; ?> 
        Title <?php echo $row[1]; ?> 
        Category <?php echo $row[2]; ?>  
        Year <?php echo $row[3]; ?>  
        ISBN <?php echo $row[4]; ?>

        Sleeve <br><?php echo "<img src='" . $row['filepath'] ." ' height='200' width='200'/>"; ?>


                  <form action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
                  <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
                  <input type="hidden" name="isbndel" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>">
                  <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"> 
                    </pre></form></div> 

    <div class="edit">
        <pre>               
      <form action="sqltest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><pre>
        Author <input type="text" name="ed_author" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
         Title <input type="text" name="ed_title" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>">
      Category <input type="text" name="ed_category" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>">
          Year <input type="text" name="ed_year" value="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>">
          ISBN <input type="text" name="hid_isbn" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>"readonly>

               <input type="file" name="image2">
               <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes">
               <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="SUBMIT EDIT">

        </pre></form>
     </div>
   </div> 
<?php
  }


  $result->close();
  $conn->close();


  function get_post($conn, $var)
  {
    return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  }
  ?>


  </html>
```

---

**RESOLUTION**: Templating - meda (reply&answer) shows the way forward (or rather out of) the above code which I recognise is really messy to look at and handle. But to deal with this present code, the immediate fix involves shifting the lines of code that deal with creating the new connection(`$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db`) from the sqltest.php to classics.php in the example. The logical extension of this would be templating.

Comment: Where is the `get_post` function? Could you post that?

Comment: It's right there at the end of the code:   `function get_post($conn, $var)
  {
    return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may more than one issues with your code.

[**MYSQL Keywords and Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

You need to add back tics to escsape mysql reserved keywords such as `TYPE` or `YEAR`.

In that case you need to rename to column or escape it using back ticks `

```
`type`='$ed_category', `year`='$ed_year'
```

---

[**Model–view–controller**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

You should not mix your queries and your HTML this way, learn about PHP page templating, most importantly design and structural patterns.

If you don't do this your code will get very messy and error prone. Then you might as well use a popular framework.

You can improve your code like this:

**Data Model**

```
<?php

class Classics
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct(\Mysqli $conn)
    {
        $this->$conn = $conn;
    }

    function insert_classics($author, $title, $category, $year, $isbn, $filename, $filepath, $filetype)
    {

        $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES ('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn', '$filename', '$filepath', '$filetype')";
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
            $this->conn->error . "<br><br>";

    }

    function update_classics($ed_author, $ed_title, $ed_category, $ed_year, $filename, $filepath, $filetype, $hid_isbn)
    {

        $query = "UPDATE classics SET author='$ed_author', title='$ed_title', `type`='$ed_category', `year`='$ed_year', filename='$filename', filepath='$filepath', filetype='$filetype'WHERE isbn='$hid_isbn'";


        $result = $this->conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "EDIT with image failed: $query<br>" .
            $this->conn->error . "<br><br>";
    }


    function update_author($ed_author, $ed_title, $ed_category, $ed_year, $hid_isbn)
    {

        $query = "UPDATE classics SET author='$ed_author', title='$ed_title', `type`='$ed_category', `year`='$ed_year' WHERE isbn='$hid_isbn'";

        $result = $this->conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "EDIT with image failed: $query<br>" . $this->conn->error . "<br><br>";

    }


    function get_classics()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $this->conn->error);

        $rows = $result->num_rows;

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }


        $result->close();
        return $row;

    }

}
```

All the SQL in one class, then use it like this for example:

**View**

```
<?php
include('login_news.php');
include('css.php');
include('classics.php');


$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<form action="sqltest.php" method="POST" name="theForm" id="theForm">
    <select name="options">
        <option value="classics">Classics</option>
        <option value="horror">Horror</option>
        <option value="recipes">Recipes</option>
        <option value="historic">Historic</option>
        <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
        <option value="educational">Educational</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Load page"/>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['options']) && $_POST['options'] === "classics") {

    $classics = new Classics($conn);
    $rows = $classics->get_classics();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        ?>
        <div class="slab">
            <div class="present">
        <pre>
        Author <?php echo $row[0]; ?>
            Title <?php echo $row[1]; ?>
            Category <?php echo $row[2]; ?>
            Year <?php echo $row[3]; ?>
            ISBN <?php echo $row[4]; ?>

            Sleeve <br><?php echo "<img src='" . $row['filepath'] . " ' height='200' width='200'/>"; ?>


            <form action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
                  <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
                  <input type="hidden" name="isbndel" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>">
                  <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD">
                    </pre>
            </form>
            </div>

            <div class="edit">
        <pre>
      <form action="sqltest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><pre>
        Author <input type="text" name="ed_author" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
         Title <input type="text" name="ed_title" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>">
      Category <input type="text" name="ed_category" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>">
          Year <input type="text" name="ed_year" value="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>">
          ISBN <input type="text" name="hid_isbn" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>" readonly>

               <input type="file" name="image2">
               <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes">
               <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="SUBMIT EDIT">

        </pre>
      </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}?>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - this helps, and templating is definitely my immediate goal. This showed me the way to go. Also  I decided not to go with a framework because figuring out their functions was getting ersatz and removes one further from the fundamentals of all this - such as good practices that u explain.

Comment: Im glad it helped, are you able to execute the queries

Comment: Yes, am able to handle the queries now - the immediate fix to the messy code was to take out the first few lines of code dealing with the connection and put it in the classics.php - then the mvc u speak of (which I am reading about now) or the separation  of queries from html seems to be the natural way to handle this.